# Is there a setter method used here in this method implementation?

Tags: objective-c

Just looking at an example of code which implements a method called bodyMassIndex.

Rather than access the instance variables in the class directly, the idea is that accessor methods are used instead. I'm just not sure whether both setter and getter methods are present here and that's what I need to ask about.

Here is the code:

```
-(float)bodyMassIndex

float h = [self heightInMeters];
return [self weightInKilos] / (h*h);
```

What I am really wondering is where is the setter method in this code? I see the getter methods being used, in terms of the two messages `heightInMeters` and `weightInKilos` being sent to the instance of the class, but I'm not seeing the setter methods. Is it that the setter methods are not going to be used in the implementation of other methods?

I have seen the setters used in the related main.c file for this program so I know how they get used in terms of setting a value indirectly.
Are setters only used purely **outside of** the class then?

*I really don't like to copy and paste code and ask about it. I'd rather ask questions about code I've written myself that I'm having problems with, but as I am new to accessor methods I haven't any choice this time!*

Comment: Why do you think there _should_ be setters used here?

Comment: I can see the getter methods clearly, which are fetching the values that have been set for the heightInMeters and for the weightInKilos. I'm just wondering if the variable 'h' is related to the setter method here. Like, sure, I don't expect values to be initially set here, but once they are, are they stored in h, and used here?

Comment: `h` is really only used here to avoid having to write `return [self weightInKilos] / ([self heightInMeters] * [self heightInMeters]);`. That is, `h` is a local variable to the method and not a member variable of the object.

Comment: That is what had me confused I think as in the implementation file for the class, h, had been declared as representing _heightInMeters in its setter method, as in: -(void)setHeightInMeters:(float)h { _heightInMeters = h; }

Comment: So is this a separate and distinct variable h, then?

Comment: Any variable declared in the method signature like your comment, or the method body like your question, is a local variable to that method, and is completely separate from other declaration... the technical term for this is "scope", we say the variable `h` is only scoped to that method, you can search e.g. 'c scope rules' to learn more

Comment: Ok, great, thanks for that reminder re scope. So the h is a handy variable only used to represent the heightInMeters here. Ok, so there isn't any kind of setter method used here then? Like the setter is there implicitly only, as in, via the getter method fetching the value previously and otherwise set in main()?

Answer (score 2):

This will (most likely) be the getter for a read only property, because it is computed and there is no backing iVar referenced.  heightInMeters and weightInKilos are probably read/write and this is just a little helper, where there would be no point keeping track of it (bodyMassIndex) when it is just the product of two other properties, doing so just invited conflict and errors